# JavaScript code not waiting til page loads after button click

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fill out a form and click submit and then I need to wait until the next page loads and continue working with elements. It seems like the code after the button click happens before the next page appears and the DOM has loaded. I've tried to use a while loop to check the readyState but that doesn't seem to work either. Any suggestions? Here is an example of what I'm trying to do assuming I have the submit button element in variable submitButton.

I've tried to use a while loop to check the readyState but that doesn't seem to work either. Any suggestions? Here is an example of what I'm trying to do assuming I have the submit button element in variable submitButton.

```
submitButton.click();
var errors = document.getElementsByClassName('error'); // Should be done after new page load
if (errors.length > 0)
{
  console.log("There are some errors");
}
```

Assuming there will be some errors on the next page, there should be a message printed out, but this doesn't happen.

Comment: Why would it wait? Submitting a form automatically loads the new page, and any JS on the page you've just left gets forgotten.

Comment: Im running the javascript through a chrome extension, I'm not too familiar with JS or chrome extensions. Is there a way that I can have it "remember" to check for errors after clicking the button?

Comment: If you're just trying to validate the form, then call `preventDefault` on the submit event, then run your validation logic - if there are any errors, display them to the user, if not then resubmit the form.

Comment: I'm not actually the creator of the form. I'm trying to write this extension to repeatedly request a ticket (which I am assuming will not be available). There's no way to check if a ticket is available until after I click the button.

Comment: I'm completely unfamiliar with making Chrome extensions, so I don't really understand the context. But it appears you're trying to add some Javascript to validate the form, and I just explained the usual way to do that. It's not clear why you can't do this - but I apologise if I misunderstood.

Comment: Alright, I think the main source of confusion is that I'm not trying to validate the contents of the form. I'm trying to request a ticket and the appearance of errors on the following page actually depends on whether there's a ticket in the system (not related at all to my inputs on the form). Now that I know the javascript will be erased with the new loading of a page I do think it will be something I have to configure in the chrome extension.

Comment: Maybe you could have your extension listen for changes to each input element on the form and save their current values in variables (or even in localStorage if needed.) Then on the next page, you could run the checks against those saved values.

Comment: Got it working for now, I have it setup to where it just runs my javascript anytime a page is loaded with a specific address. There's only two pages I need to handle and they can easily be checked so I think I'm all set for now. I'm using content_scripts on my chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.onload()
Just pass a function thaz does what your script is currently meant to be doing
The function will be called when the page is loaded so you can use it to implement the functionality you want

Answer (score -2):

encapsulate the whole code inside function i write but for this you would need the jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   //Your code here
});
```

For refrence 
[Document Ready function jquery](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)